# oracle XML DB fails to validate <xs:pattern> with RegEx that validates in other tools

Tags: java, regex, xml, oracle, validation

I created this simple type with a regex pattern.

```
<xs:simpleType name="dotString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="dot\s\b([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-3][0-9][0-9][0-9]|40[0-8][0-9]|409[0-8])\b">
    </xs:pattern>
    </xs:restriction>    
</xs:simpleType>
```

Its required only to accept string "dot [1 to 4098]" number.
This regular expression pattern works perfect to my requirements in a tool called Kiki(0.5.6), and in others online web pages.
...But when I put it in a XSD and try to use it against a XML... the validation fails with a error: "Could not parse schema".

From my tests, it is related with the "\b" in the regex.
If I remove the "\b" from the XSD, the XML validation runs OK, does not give any error, but the results are not the expected ones. 
It does not validate properly.... something like this passes: "dot 5000"

Is the "\b" not supported in oracle xml db?
What is the replacement for the "\b" that I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `\b` ([word boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes)) isn't one of the [Perl-influenced extensions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_posix003.htm#SQLRF55544) that Oracle supports.

If that is supposed to be the entire string then you could use the `\W` non-word class instead:

```
^\W*dot\s([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-3][0-9][0-9][0-9]|40[0-8][0-9]|409[0-8])\W*$
```

With some demo values:

```
with t as (
  select 'dot 1' as val from dual
  union all select 'dot 1 ' as val from dual
  union all select ' dot 1' as val from dual
  union all select ' dot 1 ' as val from dual
  union all select 'dot 4098' as val from dual
  union all select 'dot 4098 ' as val from dual
  union all select ' dot 4098' as val from dual
  union all select ' dot 4098 ' as val from dual
  union all select 'dot 4099' as val from dual
  union all select 'dot 5000' as val from dual
  union all select 'dot 1211' as val from dual
  union all select ' dot 1211 ' as val from dual
  union all select 'x dot 1211 ' as val from dual
  union all select ' dot 1211 x' as val from dual
)
select '<' || val || '>' as val,
  case when regexp_like(val,
    '^\W*dot\s([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-3][0-9][0-9][0-9]|40[0-8][0-9]|409[0-8])\W*$'
    ) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as matches
from t;
```

that pattern gets:

```
VAL           MATCHES
------------- -------
<dot 1>       Yes    
<dot 1 >      Yes    
< dot 1>      Yes    
< dot 1 >     Yes    
<dot 4098>    Yes    
<dot 4098 >   Yes    
< dot 4098>   Yes    
< dot 4098 >  Yes    
<dot 4099>    No     
<dot 5000>    No     
<dot 1211>    Yes    
< dot 1211 >  Yes    
<x dot 1211 > No     
< dot 1211 x> No
```

I'm not sure if that covers all your requirements though.

Comment: Ok, thank you.
Now the XML can be validated :) ... but fails always.
-" "dot 1211" is not a valid value!

... back to the drawing board! with "/b" was just perfect :(

Comment: @paulooliveira - I've updated it with something that's closer to the word boundary check. I'm not entirely sure what your requirements are for preceding and following values; this just allows whitespace either side. Hope that helps move you forward anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the script. 
In SQL is working.... but it is still failing the validation in:
- XmlTools in Notepad++
- W3C schema validator (http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation)

Looks like this works in the database, but not in the rest of the world.
I will try now with the oracles SCHEMAVALIDATE()

Comment: Confirmed, this regular expression also fails when using the oracle schema validation.

    <xs:simpleType name="dot1qString">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="^\W*dot\s([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-3][0-9][0-9][0-9]|40[0-8][0-9]|409[0-8])\W*$" />
                </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>

ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LSX-00333: literal "dot 4096" is not valid with respect to the pattern

Comment: Its confirmed, there are problems (bugs) with oracle pattern validation. 
In my case, the bug can be replicated in 11g and 12c... so, that's sorted.

Comment: @paulooliveira - OK, thanks for the updates. Hope you find a solution.